# Loading dump.rdb fails

Tags: redis

I want to transfer redis database from one server to another. So I transferred dump.rdb after save command to the new server and placed as a dbfile. When I start redis server, everything seems working fine for a while; used_memory increases as file loads:

```
127.0.0.1:6379> info

# Memory
used_memory:3142064944
used_memory_human:2.93G
used_memory_rss:0
used_memory_peak:3142064944
used_memory_peak_human:2.93G
used_memory_lua:33792
mem_fragmentation_ratio:0.00
mem_allocator:jemalloc-3.6.0

# Persistence
loading:1

127.0.0.1:6379> info

# Memory
used_memory:4164419680
used_memory_human:3.88G
used_memory_rss:0
used_memory_peak:4164419680
used_memory_peak_human:3.88G
used_memory_lua:33792
mem_fragmentation_ratio:0.00
mem_allocator:jemalloc-3.6.0

# Persistence
loading:1
```

After a few seconds process stops:

```
Could not connect to Redis at 127.0.0.1:6379: Connection refused
```

I think restarting redis server restarts db loading from scratch and cannot be finished

```
127.0.0.1:6379> keys *
(error) LOADING Redis is loading the dataset in memory
```

There is nothing in the redis log file.

Comment: In order to get help you should provide logs of the server crashing. Probably it crashes for out of memory or because the RDB file version does not match.

Comment: @antirez the problem was low memory of the server. Thanks.

Comment: You are welcome, glad you found the issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We had a similar error with our redis database and it turned out to be a memory issue. Increasing the amount of memory solved the issue. You can check logs to see if redis needs more memory or not.